# Golf Results: Displaying related list values in Python (beginner)

Tags: python

Here is my code with comments.  I am trying to figure out how to properly match the name of the winning golfer with their score, and display the golfer's name in the output along with the winning score.

```py
def main():                                             #define the main function
    golferNames = []                                    #create empty list for golferNames
    golferScores = []                                   #create empty list for golferScores
    golferCount = inputInfo(golferNames,golferScores)   #call inputInfo function; pass lists
    winner = displayReport(golferNames,golferScores)    #call displayReport function; pass lists

    #print winner's results
    print('Winner is ',winner,'with score ',min(golferScores),'out of ',golferCount,'golfers.') 

def inputInfo(golferNames,golferScores):                #define inputInfo function
    golferCount = 0                                     #assign starting value to golferCount
    another = input('Are there any golfer cards to input? (y/n)')#establish starting loop 
    while another != 'n':                               #establish while loop condition
        golferName = input('Enter name of golfer: ')
        golferNames.append(golferName)
        golferScore = int(input("Enter golfer's score: "))
        golferScores.append(golferScore)
        golferCount += 1
        another = input('Do you have more golfers to enter? (y/n)')
    return golferCount        
        
def displayReport(golferNames,golferScores):            #define displayReport function
    import datetime                                     #import the datetime module
    curDateTime = datetime.datetime.now()               #assign datetime variable
    #function goes the the golferNames list and scores lists and reads all golfers
    #and their information one line at a time in a loop:
    index = 0
    for golfer in golferNames: 
        #maintain a total of the scores and keep track of lowest score so far AND
        #display each golfer score as a row in a table to the screen using print/format
        print('SPRINGFORK AMATUER GOLF CLUB')
        print('TOURNAMENT DATE: ', curDateTime)
        print('GOLFER NAME', 'SCORE')
        print('--------------------', '-----')
    for golfer in golferNames:
        print(golferNames[index],golferScores[index])
        index += 1
        
main()  #call the main function
```

Comment: `winningScore, winningName = *sorted(list(zip(golferScores, golferNames)), key=lambda x: x[0])[0]`

Comment: @LarrytheLlama your code line returns the minimum score instead of the winning. 

Fix:
`winningScore, winningName = *sorted(list(zip(golferScores, golferNames)), key=lambda x: x[0])[-1]`

Comment: @YoavSheetrit whoops - I did think to, I just forgot. My bad.